# Getting this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined; Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: javascript, json

A bootstrap table where the JSON file should have to upload

```
  <div class="container mt-2 mb-2">
    <table
      class="tableprocessor"
      data-toggle="table"
      data-pagination="true"
      data-search="true"
      data-search-align="left"
      data-show-column="true"
      data-show-toggle="true"
      data-show-refresh="true"
      data-show-fullscreen="true"
      data-show-pagination-switch="true"
      data-pagination-pre-text="Previous"
      data-pagination-next-text="Next"
      data-pagination-h-align="left"
      data-pagination-detail-h-align="right"
      data-page-list="[5, 10, 15, All]"
      data-url="processor.json">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th rowspan="2" data-checkbox="true" data-valign="middle"></th>
          <th colspan="8" data-align="center">Header</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th data-sortable="true" data-switchable="false">Brand</th>
          <th data-sortable="true" data-switchable="false">Name</th>
          <th data-sortable="true">Core Count</th>
          <th data-sortable="true">Core Speed</th>
          <th data-sortable="true">TDP</th>
          <th data-sortable="true">Price</th>
          <th data-sortable="false">Rating</th>
          <th data-sortable="false">Add</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
```

This is the code used before the  tag.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.9.2/umd/popper.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.18.3/locale/bootstrap-table-en-US.min.js" integrity="sha512-VyHDnIKFpnUT870o8K2eftG/+OvDM+8OPZRP9oNnkInxtjM5aKGd6DTWHkGVp9QjsyI7kZZOWuiBAwvMRuTnJg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.getJSON("processor.json", function(data){
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val){
      items.push("<tr>");
      items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.brand+"</td>");
      items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.name+"</td>");
      items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.coreCount+"</td>");
      items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.coreSpeed+"</td>");
      items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.tdp+"</td>");
      items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.price+"</td>");
      items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.rating+"</td>");
      items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.add+"</td>");
      items.push("</tr>");  
   });
   $('tbody/',{html:items.join("")}).appendTo("#tableprocessor");
});
</script>
```

This is the JSON FILE which are stored locally and named as processor.json

```
 [{
   "brand": "AMD",
   "name": "Threadripper 3990X 64-Core 3.0GHz",
   "coreCount": 64,
   "coreSpeed": "3GHz",
   "tdp": "280W",
   "price": "-",
   "rating": 10,
   "add": "Add"
 },
 {
   "brand": "AMD",
   "name": "Threadripper 3970X 32-Core 3.7GHz",
   "coreCount": 32,
   "coreSpeed": "3.7GHz",
   "tdp": "280W",
   "price": "-",
   "Rating": 10,
   "add": "Add"
 }]
```

Comment: As far as I can tell you've included bootstrap *three* times...? 4.0.0, 4.3.1 and 4.6.0. This doesn't explain the error however, since the links work fine and if I copy that massive script chunk into a fiddle, I can access `$` perfectly fine. How are you looking at the html file? Are you double-clicking it?

Comment: what to do. I'm new in javascript . I only know about html and css

Comment: The title of  the post says "...Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined;..." Maybe jQuery is not loaded.

Comment: Are you running this off a server? Does it say `localhost/...` in your browser or does it start with `file:///...`? Still, I have no idea why you're getting that error. Your problem is currently "not reproducible", so you need to show your actual html file, not pieces of it in arbitrary order.

Comment: I can only see the table header not the data which is stored in json file and after right clicking on the page then i get error main.js:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at main.js:16

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I think i cant load the json file.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` means that either the jQuery script failed to load or you're using `$` before the jQuery <script> tag. That's why I am asking specifically about the order of things in your html document. The error occurs in `main.js` but the code in your question doesn't contain `<script src="main.js"></script>` Wherever that tag is, it needs to be *below* the other scripts, in the same document.

Comment: jquery.min.js:2 GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/src/processor.json?search= 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Where is the `src` folder? Is `processor.json` inside it?

Comment: I'm using <head><link><script src></script><header>"Bootstrap Table"</header><script src="All the file where the bootstrap included"><script " the JSON loading script"></body>

Comment: The proper structure is `<html><head> library scripts here </head><body> html content here <script src="main.js"></script></body></html>`

Comment: now as mentioned I have done all the things. Now I'm getting this error "jquery.min.js:2 GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/src/processor.json 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: That is why I asked you about your server side file structure. But you didn't answer me.

Comment: in the src i have a link of 'main.js' file. and inside main.js file I have JSON file code

Comment: processor.json is in the main file which is saved locally

Comment: How is a file inside another file...? Anyway, as you can clearly see from the error message, you code is trying to load a file called "processor.json" from inside the "src" folder. It's already suspect that your server is serving the folder above "src" as root, but I have no idea what your setup is since you don't give any information about your server or its file structure. This is a massive waste of time and I will have to leave this question if you don't provide the info we need.

Comment: I have a folder which included as follow. **1.**  assets(all image files)  **2.** css  **3.** js (which include 'main.js') **4.** src (all HTML File) and last **5.** is processor.json

Comment: I have  <head><script src="../js/main.js"></script></head> which include JSON SCRIPT

Comment: In that case you need `$.getJSON("/processor.json")`

Comment: Thank you so much finally the data is loaded. Thank you @Chris G for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it there was minor errors in your code. This example will work. I removed all the references to Bootstrap because it is not important for the functionality.

The most important changes: The html property on `$('tbody')` and then adding the `<tbody>` element in the HTML.

I turned the json file into a data-URI for testing. You can just replace the long string with your original file name (`processor.json`).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("data:application/json;base64,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", function(data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      items.push("<tr>");
      items.push("<td id=''" + key + "''>" + val.brand + "</td>");
      items.push("<td id=''" + key + "''>" + val.name + "</td>");
      items.push("<td id=''" + key + "''>" + val.coreCount + "</td>");
      items.push("<td id=''" + key + "''>" + val.coreSpeed + "</td>");
      items.push("<td id=''" + key + "''>" + val.tdp + "</td>");
      items.push("<td id=''" + key + "''>" + val.price + "</td>");
      items.push("<td id=''" + key + "''>" + val.rating + "</td>");
      items.push("<td id=''" + key + "''>" + val.add + "</td>");
      items.push("</tr>");
    });
    $('tbody').html(items.join("")).appendTo("#tableprocessor");
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Processors</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.9.2/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mt-2 mb-2">
    <table class="tableprocessor" data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true" data-search="true" data-search-align="left" data-show-column="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-refresh="true" data-show-fullscreen="true" data-show-pagination-switch="true"
      data-pagination-pre-text="Previous" data-pagination-next-text="Next" data-pagination-h-align="left" data-pagination-detail-h-align="right" data-page-list="[5, 10, 15, All]">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th rowspan="2" data-checkbox="true" data-valign="middle"></th>
          <th colspan="8" data-align="center">Header</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th data-sortable="true" data-switchable="false">Brand</th>
          <th data-sortable="true" data-switchable="false">Name</th>
          <th data-sortable="true">Core Count</th>
          <th data-sortable="true">Core Speed</th>
          <th data-sortable="true">TDP</th>
          <th data-sortable="true">Price</th>
          <th data-sortable="false">Rating</th>
          <th data-sortable="false">Add</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: One of OP's specific problems is how to properly load a server-side JSON file. Your answer doesn't address that.

Comment: Actually, I also want to know that, the references which you have corrected it has to put on <head><head> tags. and also the JSON file script is in MAIN.js which is linked under head tag as <head><script src="../js/main.js"></script></head>. Is this is the right way?

Comment: @ChrisG I know that but it is kind of hard to show here in Stackoverflow.

Comment: @SantoshChauhan yes that is right. But is your JS is goning into <head> make sure that the document has been loaded before you manipulate it. Add $(document).ready(function() { .... }); around the code that is going to run initially. I updated my answer

Comment: Thank you @chrwahl for help